# Sort the columns in a table when a row is fetched sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table which looks like this:

```
+----------------------------------+-
|    Id   |  Sub1   |  Sub2 | Sub3 |
+----------------------------------+-
|  X      |   100   |  55   |  65  |
|  Y      |   45    |  55   |  65  |
|  Z      |   95    |  55   |  65  |
+----------------------------------+-
```

How do I sort the the columns fetched for a specific row?
`Select * from MARKS_TABLE WHERE Id='X'` SORT the columns Sub1, Sub2, Sub3 should return 55, 65, 100.

I thought of using ORDERBY but with ORDERBY you need to know which columns to sortby which doesn't work in this case.

SQL Table to play with:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7d954/1

Comment: @GordonLinoff My bad SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, I would use conditional aggregation and `apply`:

```
select t.id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then sub end) as sub1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then sub end) as sub2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then sub end) as sub3
from t apply
     (select v.sub, row_number() over (order by v.sub) as seqnum
      from (values (t.sub1), (t.sub2), (t.sub3)
           ) as v(sub)
     ) v;
```

You can do something similar in Oracle 12c, by the way, but the syntax would be a little different in earlier versions.

The `apply` expands each row into multiple rows, for each value of `sub?`.  The `row_number()` provides a sequential number, based on the ordering.  Then the outer query uses conditional aggregation to get the three values you want in order.

Comment: @GordonLindoff could you please explain as well? I'm not able to follow

Comment: added a sql fiddle link to play with

Answer (score 1):

You could use UNION ALL:

```
  select sub1
  from marks
  where ID = 1
  union all
  select sub2
  from Marks
  where ID = 1
  union all
  select sub3
  from marks
  where ID = 1
  order by 1
```

Comment: Added a fiddle link to test with

Comment: isn't this super ineffective with querying 3 times?

Comment: You would have to test it against other solutions, but the page the data is stored on would be loaded into a buffer with the first query, so you would be reading from memory thereafter.  If it's performance you are after then you would be better off normalising your table.